# How to inject objects in custom object

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm implementing a update function that will use a server response to handle the update. Now my update need to ask the user (in a dialog) to restart the application. The only injection I can do in the class is the IEclipseContext.

Now how can I get the UISynchronize of the current running Eclipse RCP application? So that I safely can run this method:

```
private void showMessage(UISynchronize sync, final String message) {
        sync.syncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(null, "Information", message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISynchronize` is in the application `IEclipseContext` so it will be available in any context except the OSGi services context.

All that `UISynchronize` does is call `Display.asyncExec` so if you haven't got a context available just use the traditional

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(....)
```